Monitor Uniswap Swap Events of hundreds of pairs concurrently
I have a basic POC that listens to a swap event in a specific pair on UniswapV2. This works well. My issue is when I try to run this for say, 10 or more pairs Infura starts giving me rate limiting responses. I am not sure what the issue is. My code is something along those lines
function getSwapEvents(token0Address, token1Address, pairAddress, tokenSymbol, totalSupply,token0Decimals, token1Decimals) {
  const pairContract = new ethers.Contract(pairAddress, UNISWAP_V2_PAIR_ABI, provider);

  pairContract.on("Swap", async (sender, amount0In, amount1In, amount0Out, amount1Out, to, event) => {

    console.log("Swap occured on ", tokenSymbol)
  });
}

And I am running this function for all CAs that I need. For example
data.forEach((entry) => {
        const { token0Address, token1Address, pairAddress, tokenSymbol, totalSupply, token0Decimals, token1Decimals } = entry;
        getSwapEvents(token0Address, token1Address, pairAddress, tokenSymbol, totalSupply, token0Decimals, token1Decimals)
    });

With a handful of contracts like 4-5 it works well. But when I use more I get this error from Infura

  code: 'SERVER_ERROR',
  request: FetchRequest {},
  response: FetchResponse {},
  error: undefined,
  info: {
    requestUrl: 'https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/<API-KEY>',
    responseBody: '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32005,"message":"batch item count exceeded"}}',
    responseStatus: '599 CLIENT ESCALATED SERVER ERROR (429 Too Many Requests; exceeded maximum retry limit)'
  },
  shortMessage: 'exceeded maximum retry limit'
}

I know I can use The Graph but the issue is I want to get swaps live as they come, and I want this to scale to say thousands of CAs in parallel. What am I missing and do you have any alternative design suggestions?

Sure, you can listen to all the pairs simultaneously with this:
const iface = new ethers.utils.Interface(UNISWAP_V2_PAIR_ABI);
const filter = {
    topics: [
        iface.getEventTopic("Swap")
    ]
}
provider.on(filter, (log, event) => {
    // ...
})

You will get logs from every contract which emits "Swap", so you need to ignore those. If you have an array pairs with all valid pair's addresses then something like:
provider.on(filter, (log, event) => {
    const pair = log.address;
    // check that pair is in your list
    if (pairs.includes(pair)) {
        const parsedLog = iface.parseLog(log);
        console.log(parsedLog);
    }
})


So does this listen to every swap event on chain that conforms to the swap event Uniswap uses? And I then filter out my pairs? isn't than inefficient compared to listening to only the events I care about? i.e.
const pairContract = new ethers.Contract(pairAddress, UNISWAP_V2_PAIR_ABI, provider);
If its as efficient this simplifies my design quite a bit. When I say efficient I mean in terms of RPC requests to the node.

it's more efficient since you're making a single subscription

Thanks! So where can I learn a bit about how this works? My intuitiuon was that the cost would be per event received? If I subscribe to all possible events then I will receive more? Compared to subscribing only the the specific pairs I am interested. I would like if you could point me to the right direction.

In terms of cost on CPU/memory, I've no idea if a single big subscription is more efficient than more smaller ones. But opening a single connection has less chances of triggering an infura error, so it's better for you. I can't find much docs beside this https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interacting-with-geth/rpc/pubsub
